# Get all cells coordinates for a Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range

Tags: c#, excel, add-in, range, cells

Is there any method/property that I could use to get a string array of range's selected items ?

In example :
The range `$B$2:$C$3` would give a string array with the following values : `$B$2 $B$3 $C$2 $C$3`

**EDIT ::**
I found the answer to my question on [this post.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6498229/1035271)
In fact, I need to use the following procedure :

```
    foreach (Range c in myRange)
    {
        string changedCell = c.get_Address(
            Type.Missing, Type.Missing, 
            XlReferenceStyle.xlA1, 
            Type.Missing, Type.Missing
        );  
        MessageBox.Show("Address:" + changedCell + " Value: " + c.Value2);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, there isn't a property that can give cell addresses of a given range in the format, you are expecting.

Here is the VBA code to get what you are looking for

```
Function GetCellAddresses(ByVal srcRange As Range) As Variant
Dim cellAddresses As Variant

Dim cellCtr As Long
Dim cellCount As Long

Dim cell As Range

If Not srcRange Is Nothing Then
    cellCtr = 1
    cellCount = srcRange.Cells.Count
    ReDim cellAddresses(1 To cellCount)

    For Each cell In srcRange.Cells
        cellAddresses(cellCtr) = cell.Address
        cellCtr = cellCtr + 1
    Next
End If

GetCellAddresses = cellAddresses
End Function
```

To call the above, `GetCellAddresses(sheet1.Range("A1:B3"))`

EDIT: Using LINQ, this can become 1 or 2 liner.
For e.g. `var cellAddresses = srcRange.Select(c => c.Address);`

OR

`from cell in srcRange select cell.Address`